# Extracting values via Regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, dynamic-data

I am using Dynamic Data and to apply Unique key and other database level validations i have overridden the SubmitChanges function.

This gives me original error, which i am able to show to the end user. But, this message is like this:

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_CountryName_Country'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Country'. The duplicate key value is (America).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I need the following keywords of the message:

1. UNIQUE KEY
2. UK_CountryName_Country
3. America

I have written following Regex:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(e.Message.ToString(), "^Violation of (UNIQUE KEY){1} constraint '([a-zA-Z_]*)'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.([a-zA-Z]*)'. The duplicate key value is ")
```

I have succeeded in getting #1 & #2, but #3.

Can anyone help me. Also, is there any cleaner way to achieve it.
FYI: I would be catching other types of database errors as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example expression, it seemed you were trying to match the `Country` from `dbo.Country` instead of `America` as you asked, so I included both in my expression/code:

```
 Dim ExpressionText As String = "^Violation of (?<KeyType>.*?) constraint '(?<ConstraintName>[^']*)'\.[^']*'(?<ObjectName>[^']*)'[^(]*\((?<KeyValue>[^)]*)\)"
 Dim SearchText As String = "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_CountryName_Country'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Country'. The duplicate key value is (America). " _
                               & vbCrLf & "The statement has been terminated."
 Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(ExpressionText)
 Dim mc As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = regex.Match(SearchText)

 Response.Write(mc.Groups("KeyType").Value)           ' writes UNIQUE KEY
 Response.Write(mc.Groups(1).Value)                   ' writes UNIQUE KEY
 Response.Write(mc.Groups("ConstraintName").Value)    ' writes UK_CountryName_Country
 Response.Write(mc.Groups(2).Value)                   ' writes UK_CountryName_Country
 Response.Write(mc.Groups("ObjectName").Value)        ' writes dbo.Country
 Response.Write(mc.Groups(3).Value)                   ' writes dbo.Country
 Response.Write(mc.Groups("KeyValue").Value)          ' writes America
 Response.Write(mc.Groups(4).Value)                   ' writes America
```

The expression is designed to be very tolerant of the type of error message, as there are other types of Key Constraints that can be violated. I could not find a list of the possible errors, but here is a breakdown of the expression:

```
^Violation of                   # Match literal text
(?<KeyType>.*?) constraint      # Capture the words that come before  " constraint"
'(?<ConstraintName>[^']*)'\.    # Capture whatever is inside the single quotes:  '
[^']*                           # Match anything up to the next single quote
'(?<ObjectName>[^']*)'          # Capture whatever is inside the single quotes
[^(]*                           # Match anything up to the next open parentheses:  ( 
\((?<KeyValue>[^)]*)\)          #Capture whatever is inside the parentheses
```

You can get rid of the parts that look like `?<Something>` if you do not want to use named capturing groups, and only want to use the numbers

Comment: Did anyone tell you that you are an awesome Regex builder? Success in the very first attempt. Can you also guide me some links for learning Regex. Thanks.

Comment: A very good tutorial (taught me 90% of what I know about regex) is at [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) - the author of that site also makes a piece of software called RegexBuddy that is excellent at emulating and helping to debug all sorts of Regexes (in all sorts of languages/implementations - or "regex flavors" as they are often called)

Answer (score 1):

Since the last value is near the end you can just match to the end of the line, being careful not to match the final period:

```
".... The duplicate key value is (.*)\.$"
```

Comment: yea, very true and nice. I am looking for some other work around to catch these error. If i don't get it then i shall mark it as answer. Thanks for answering. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
^Violation\s+of\s+(.*?)'(.*?)'.*?\((.*)\)
```

I am unaware of how all possible errors look like but the regex above will capture :

```
Group 1:    UNIQUE KEY constraint      
Group 2:    UK_CountryName_Country
Group 3:    America
```